# Javascript get radio button values form div positions

Tags: javascript, html

OK, here is me trying to create quiz application, and I've spend 8+ hours trying to figure out what's wrong. I just give up, so pls help me if you can. Situation is that I use DOM to create radio input that you can pick to choose answer on question, and every time u click next, another question is showed in div tags, while previous div tags are deleted. I want to store result in a way that after all questions are done i'll notify user in alert window or something about how many were correct answered. Problem is that I can't find what am I doing so wrong that.

```
answers = document.getElementsByName('quiz');
if(answers[1].checked){
       alert("gj");
    }
```

This works fine in browser console, it alerts me if user selected radio button number 1. But when i put this inside my script it does nothing.
I am guessing problem is somewhere in how I created whole start() function, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Complete code:
    
    
      
        Dynamic Quiz

```
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "Question1?", 
    choices: ["Answer1", "Answer2", "Answer3", "Answer4"],
    CorrectAnswer:0},
    {
    question: "Question2?", 
    choices: ["Answer6", "Answer7"],
    CorrectAnswer:0}
    ];

var currentQuestion=0;
var currentAnswer=0;
var correctAnswer=0;
var answers;
var div2;

function createDiv(){
    var div=document.createElement("div");
    div2=document.getElementById("content").appendChild(div);
}

function createQuestion(question){
    var q = document.createElement('p');
    q.innerHTML=question;
    div2.appendChild(q);
}

function createRadio(id){
    var radio = document.createElement('input');
    radio.setAttribute("type","radio");
    radio.setAttribute("name","quiz");
    radio.setAttribute("id",id);
    div2.appendChild(radio);
}

function createLabel(id,text){
    var lab = document.createElement('label'); 
    lab.setAttribute("id",id);
    lab.setAttribute("for",id);

    lab.innerHTML=text;
    div2.appendChild(lab);
}

function checkAnswer(){
answers = document.getElementsByName('quiz');
if(answers[1].checked){
       alert("gj");
    }
}

function remover(){ //removes content for next question

  var myNode = document.getElementById("content");
  while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
  }
}

function start(){ 

remover();
createDiv();
createQuestion(allQuestions[currentQuestion].question); 

//create all radio answers for question in div
for (var i = 0; i<allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices.length;i++){
    createDiv();
    createRadio(allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[i]);
    createLabel(allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[i],allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[i]);
}

checkAnswer();

currentQuestion++;

if (currentQuestion === allQuestions.length){ //just sto stop from going infinite
currentQuestion=allQuestions.length-1; }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload=start()>

<div id="main">
<div id="content"></div> 
</div>
<div id="butn">
<input type="submit" value="Start" onClick="start()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can achieve your requirement.
You can simply add a new function on next button.
checkout the snippet

```js
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "Question1?", 
    choices: ["Answer1", "Answer2", "Answer3", "Answer4"],
    CorrectAnswer:0},
    {
    question: "Question2?", 
    choices: ["Answer6", "Answer7"],
    CorrectAnswer:0}
    ];

var currentQuestion=0;
var currentAnswer=0;
var correctAnswer=0;
var answers;
var div2;

function createDiv(){
    var div=document.createElement("div");
    div2=document.getElementById("content").appendChild(div);
}

function createQuestion(question){
    var q = document.createElement('p');
    q.innerHTML=question;
    div2.appendChild(q);
}

function createRadio(id){
    var radio = document.createElement('input');
    radio.setAttribute("type","radio");
    radio.setAttribute("name","quiz");
    radio.setAttribute("id",id);
    div2.appendChild(radio);
}

function createLabel(id,text){
    var lab = document.createElement('label'); 
    lab.setAttribute("id",id);
    lab.setAttribute("for",id);

    lab.innerHTML=text;
    div2.appendChild(lab);
}

function checkAnswer(){
answers = document.getElementsByName('quiz');

if(answers[0].checked){
       alert("correct answer");
    }
  else{
  alert("wrong") ; 
  }
}

function remover(){ //removes content for next question

  var myNode = document.getElementById("content");
  while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
  }
}
function next(){ 
  checkAnswer();
  remover();
  start();
}
function start(){ 


createDiv();
createQuestion(allQuestions[currentQuestion].question); 

//create all radio answers for question in div
for (var i = 0; i<allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices.length;i++){
    createDiv();
    createRadio(allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[i]);
    createLabel(allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[i],allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[i]);
}



currentQuestion++;

if (currentQuestion === allQuestions.length){ //just sto stop from going infinite
currentQuestion=allQuestions.length-1; }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
</head>
<body onload="start()">

<div id="main">
<div id="content"></div> 
</div>
<div id="butn">
<input type="submit" value="Start" onClick="next()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The new element

```
document.getElementsByName('quiz');
```

is added dynamically with `appendChild()`so it won't be detected by document.getElementsByName.
You could add an `onclick` event

```
radio.setAttribute("onclick","checkAnswer()");
```

```js
var allQuestions = [{
  question: "Question1 ?",
  choices: ["Answer1", "Answer2", "Answer3", "Answer4"],
  CorrectAnswer: "Answer3"
}, {
  question: "Question2 ?",
  choices: ["Answer6", "Answer7"],
  CorrectAnswer: "Answer6"
}];

var currentQuestion = 0;
var currentAnswer = 0;
var correctAnswer = 0;
var answers;
var div2;

function createDiv() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div2 = document.getElementById("content").appendChild(div);
}

function createQuestion(question) {
  var q = document.createElement('p');
  q.innerHTML = question;
  div2.appendChild(q);
}

function createRadio(id) {
  var radio = document.createElement('input');
  radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
  radio.setAttribute("name", "quiz");
  radio.setAttribute("id", id);
  radio.setAttribute("onclick", "checkAnswer(id)");
  div2.appendChild(radio);
}

function createLabel(id, text) {
  var lab = document.createElement('label');
  lab.setAttribute("id", id);
  lab.setAttribute("for", id);
  lab.innerHTML = text;
  div2.appendChild(lab);
}

function checkAnswer(answer) {
  // do something with currentAnswer
  CorrectAnswer = allQuestions[currentQuestion - 1].CorrectAnswer;
  console.log("Current question: ", currentQuestion - 1);
  console.log("Current answer: ", answer);
  console.log("Correct answer: ", CorrectAnswer);
  if (answer == CorrectAnswer) {
    console.log("correct");
  }
}


function remover() { //removes content for next question

  var myNode = document.getElementById("content");
  while (myNode.firstChild) {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
  }
}

function start() {
  // when clicking start button check answer

  remover();
  createDiv();
  createQuestion(allQuestions[currentQuestion].question);

  //create all radio answers for question in div
  for (var i = 0; i < allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices.length; i++) {
    createDiv();
    createRadio(allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[i]);
    createLabel(allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[i], allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices[i]);
  }

  currentQuestion++;

}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="butn">
  <input type="submit" value="Start" onClick="start()">
```

Comment: This works nice, thanks, but now problem is that checkAnswer function gets executed every-time it's clicked on radio button, i kinda need to just to check once, is that possible? Or am i on totally wrong approach here?

Comment: @Energizem you can use the checkAnswer function to check if the last answer is correct every time you update the list of questions, you could also use it keep a counter of correct answers

Comment: @user2314737  The point you mentioned "document.getElementsByName('quiz');
is added dynamically with appendChild() so it won't be detected by document.getElementsByName. " is not correct.it will update as getElements will get the current list not as querySelector i hope.

Answer (score 1):

In your start function the `checkAnswer` executes immediately after the question is rendered at which point not radio button is checked.

If you want `checkAnswer` to execute when the radio button is clicked you can add an event handler when you create the radio button and call `checkAnswer` here and not in the `start` function.

```
function createRadio(id){
    var radio = document.createElement('input');
    radio.setAttribute("type","radio");
    radio.setAttribute("name","quiz");
    radio.setAttribute("id",id);
    radio.addEventListener("click", checkAnswer);
    div2.appendChild(radio);
}
```

Comment: thx for help, it works similar as above but do u know if is possible to checkAnswer only once, this way everytime user click radio button 1 checkAnswer is executed, and that's no good use, u can find your answer by just clicking every radio button.Is there a way just to execute it once before next button is clicked ?

Comment: You could call `checkAnswer` at the beginning of `start` instead.  You would just need to not call it the first time the start button was clicked (using your current code you could check to see if there are any quiz buttons.)

Comment: if (document.getElementsByName('quiz').length != 0) {
        checkAnswer();
    }